# jQuery undefined Data

Tags: jquery, ajax

So, I have the following js:

```
function RHP_AJAX(a, b, c)
{
jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : custom.ajax_url, 
    data : { 'action': a , id: b},
    success : function(data){
        c;          
        return false;
    }                   
}); 
}
```

Then another var:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.show', function(e) {
   var c = jQuery('.extra').html(data);
   RHP_AJAX('ajax', id, c);
});
```

The issue is `.html(data);` as `data` is not yet defined. I know the issue but I am not sure how to describe it (I am sure you guys will understand when you see the code).

How do I address the issue?

Comment: `success : function(data){
        c;          
        return false;
    }` -> is something missing here? ;)

Comment: I had `jQuery('.extra').html(data);` where `c` was used to be. But I need to change what happens after success, and I thought I would make it as a parameter. :P

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to accomplish?  Are you trying to fetch some data with Ajax and put it in the `.extra` DOM element?  Questions that only show code that doesn't work without describing what the code is supposed to do leave us to guess what you're trying to accomplish.  Put yourselves in our shoes for a second.  We need to know what your objective is with the code.

Comment: Mhmm that's exactly it. but in the `click` event, `data` is not defined yet and I am not sure how to just leave it empty till ajax is done.

Comment: Then please edit your question to say so.  It looks like some people guessed that's what you meant, but your question does NOT currently actually say that and it's quite baffling why you'd attempt to set the data into the HTML BEFORE you make the ajax call to get the data.  That threw me for a loop.

Comment: Instead of data... change it with response.. maybe conflict with ajax data...

Comment: One more thing there is no need of quotes on action

Comment: Last what is c; in success...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the function as a callback function:

```
function RHP_AJAX(a, b, callback)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
         type : 'POST',
         url  : custom.ajax_url, 
         data : { 'action': a , id: b},
         success : function(data){
             callback(data);          
            return false;
        }                   
    }); 
}


jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.show', function(e) {
   var callFunction = function(data) { jQuery('.extra').html(data);}
   RHP_AJAX('ajax', id, callFunction);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! =)  appreciate it

Comment: I made it as `success: c` then made the `var callFunction`. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a function parameter:

```
function RHP_AJAX(a, b, c){
  jQuery.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url  : custom.ajax_url, 
    data : { 'action': a , id: b},
    success : c                   
  }); 
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.show', function(e) {
   RHP_AJAX('ajax', id, function(data){
       jQuery('.extra').html(data);
   });
});
```

Comment: also no need for `return false;` ... there is nowhere to return to inside `success`. I'm guessing OP expected that to be returned to the click handler

Comment: @charlietfl in that case...no need for that function at all

Comment: Thank you. This seems like a guarantee way of dealing with it. =) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The right thing to do here would be to just pass back the Deferred from `$.ajax`

```
function RHP_AJAX(a, b) {
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : custom.ajax_url, 
        data : { 'action': a , id: b}
    });
}); 

jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.show', function(e) {
    RHP_AJAX('ajax', id).then(function(data) {
       jQuery('.extra').html(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I will give this a try. Thanks! =)

Comment: My suggestion would be to avoid the proprietary `.done()` and use the ES6 standard `.then()` which jQuery also supports.   `RHP_AJAX('ajax', id).then(...);`.  At some point, `.done()` will probably be deprecated.

Comment: @jfriend00 - agreed, just an old habit using `done` and `fail` instead of `then()` with the different callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that when you click on the `.show` element, you want to query the server and then inject that response into the `.extra` element. If so, here's my solution:

```
jQuery(document).on( 'click', '.show', function(e) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: custom.ajax_url,
        data: { "action": a, id: b },
        success: function (data) {
            jQuery(".extra").html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

It's just an issue of asynchronous programming. Have a read here: https://www.google.com/#safe=active&q=javascript%2Basynchronous%2Bprogramming

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me your code should be restructured like so:

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.show', function() {
   RHP_AJAX('ajax', id);
});

function RHP_AJAX(a, b)
{
   jQuery.ajax({
      type : 'POST',
      url  : custom.ajax_url, 
      data : { 'action': a , id: b },
      success : function(data){
         jQuery('.extra').html(data);
      }                   
   }); 
}
```

Comment: I think `RHP_AJAX()` is supposed to be generic function that can be used in more than one place for more than one action.  Usually, that's why you put a short body of code into a separate function in the first place.  Otherwise, there's no reason to use a separate function at all.

Comment: Of course. What I've written here just gets OP's code running. I debated editing it further but decided against it given the plethora of other answers that already did so here.